Installing External Wifi Adapter on Fedora 40
i'm new here, I'm trying to install an external wifi adapter ( cause my laptop is old ( not that old but still ) and it can't detect 5G signals at all ), the steps given by manufacturer is quite simple but i keep getting stumbled by this problem on the makefile
Here's the error that keeps showing
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/6.10.5-200.fc40.x86_64'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'Adapter'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:252: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/6.10.5-200.fc40.x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:2327: modules] Error 2

I'm not sure what to do ( i just got into this Linux thingy cause my laptop keeps crashing when i'm using Windows ), anyway thanks in advance for the help

Please run lsusb, find the line reporting your WiFi dongle, then copy/paste it here by [edit]ing the question. Most likely you don't need to install the drivers as provided, they likely are for older kernels only, and you need to know the exact chipset you have in order to hopefully give you an answer that works for your specific OS.

PS - It's 5GHz, not "5G" ("5G" is a typical nomenclature for the 5th generation mobile internet standard).
